# Breaking down WinMain's cmdLine in old style main()'s arguments

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to convert `WinMain`'s `cmdLine` argument to `argc` and `argv` so I can use the argument parsing function I wrote for console applications.

This would be trivial except that I want to support "quotes" too. For example:

`test.exe test1 test2 "testing testing"`

should be

```
argv[0] = "test.exe"; argv[1] = "test1"; argv[2] = "test2"; argv[3] = "testing testing";
```

I realize that cmdLine doesn't have the program name (the argv[0]); this doesn't matter I can use a dummy value.

I was thinking of doing it with a regex, `(("[^"]+")\s+)|(([^\s]+)\s*)` I'm not sure how well it would work though.. Probably not very well? Is there any function to do that in the windows api? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391%28VS.85%29.aspx) looks like it would be helpful here.

Comment: Just watch out that `CommandLineToArgvW` doesn't add a sentinel NULL value to the end of the array, so it doesn't quite have the same semantics as `argv` in standard C.

Comment: Additionally, `CommandLineToArgvW` will not expand globs. If `__argc` / `__argv` are unavailable, you should use `__getmainargs` or `__wgetmainargs` instead.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Since C89?  The language standard mandates that "`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer".  While it's redundant information, it's standard behavior, so some people rely on that.

Comment: -1 I remember `CommandLineToArgvW` doesn't handle strings in quite the same way as `__wgetmainargs` (due to escaping or whitespace, I forget which), so the latter should be used since its behavior is the same as that of a normal `argc`/`argv` passed to `main`.

Comment: Oops, should've Googled first.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using Microsoft compiler, there are public symbols `__argc`, `__argv` and `__wargv` defined in `stdlib.h`. This also applies to MinGW that uses Microsoft runtime libraries.

Comment: +1.  When these are available, I personally prefer these over `CommandLineToArgvW` since you don't have to about calling `LocalFree` and since `__argv[__argc]` and `__wargv[__argc]` are set to `NULL`.

Comment: Fantastic! But what about `envp`? **EDIT**: Ok, `_CRTIMP extern char** environ;` does the trick, I believe.

Answer (score 9):

Based on Denis K response

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn727674.aspx

This adds Windows specific entrypoint to clasic startpoint of your app:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char*, int nShowCmd)
{
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want plain int argc, char** argv arguments you have to do it on your own.

```
void fetchCmdArgs(int* argc, char*** argv) {
    // init results
    *argc = 0;

    // prepare extraction
    char* winCmd = GetCommandLine();
    int index = 0;
    bool newOption = true;
    // use static so converted command line can be
    // accessed from outside this function
    static vector<char*> argVector;

    // walk over the command line and convert it to argv
    while(winCmd[index] != 0){
        if (winCmd[index] == ' ') {
            // terminate option string
            winCmd[index] = 0;
            newOption = true;

        } else  {
            if(newOption){
                argVector.push_back(&winCmd[index]);
                (*argc)++;  
            }
            newOption = false;
        }
        index++;
    }

    // elements inside the vector are guaranteed to be continous
    *argv = &argVector[0];
}


// usage
int APIENTRY WinMain(...) {
    int argc = 0;
    char** argv;
    fetchCmdArgs(&argc, &argv);
}
```

Comment: -1 it's a lot more complicated than you make it look here. For one thing, you're not handling quotations.

Comment: Downvoted as well... this is *really* not the kind of thing people should write themselves, especially when `__argc` and `__argv` exist.